# Create HUD button without framework

Tags: cocoa, macos, interface-builder

To be clear, this is what I'm talking about:

[image]

Unfortunately, Apple hasn't provided an easy way to make this kind of button.  Most people use `BWToolKit`, but that doesn't work with Xcode 4.  Is there any way I can stylize my buttons to look like that without using `BWToolKit`?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You *can* use the BWToolKit framework with Xcode 4, it's just the Interface Builder plug-in that doesn't work.

You can link to the framework and manually assign the class of the button object and button cell to the BWToolKit classes.

Comment: I did try.  I dragged the framework into my project, then imported the framework `#import <BWToolkitFramework/BWToolkitFramework.h>`.  I then run the app (without even making any buttons) and it says this in the Console:  `dyld: Library not loaded: @loader_path/../Frameworks/BWToolkitFramework.framework/Versions/A/BWToolkitFramework
  Referenced from: /Users/myusername/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/appname-clqrpuiyrjhgvbahnaeytigeldwu/Build/Products/Debug/appname.app/Contents/MacOS/appname
  Reason: image not found`

Comment: Hmm, works for me. Make sure that you have added a framework search path of `"$(SRCROOT)"` in the build settings for your project, and that the framework is added to the **Link binary with libraries** section in the Build Phases tab.

Comment: Make sure the BWToolkit framework is also in the Copy Frameworks build step of your apps target. You can drag the framework from files section of the project to the copy step to add it.